# Correct handling of milliseconds in a date time string

Tags: date-and-time

```
DateString[{2014, 5, 7, 13, 47, 44.760}, 
  {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", " ", "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second", ".", 
  "Millisecond"}]
```

Returns 2014-05-07 13:47:44.759

The 44.760 can be 44.76 or 44.76` with no difference, replacing it with 44760/1000 does return 2014-05-07 13:47:44.760.

Presumably this is to do with 44.76 not being exactly represented as a machine precision number and milliseconds just cutting out the last 3 digits rather than rounding to 3 decimal places.

Can anyone suggest a simple fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugly but simple, and when you are only interested in milliseconds also correct for this use case.

```
DateString[{2014, 5, 7, 13, 47, Round[44.760,0.001] + 0.0001}, {"Year", "-", 
  "Month", "-", "Day", " ", "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", 
  "SecondExact"}]
```